# Express.js Route API does not work on providing a catch-all route

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack

I'm a beginner at MEAN stack and built an API using express.js

```
var User = mongoose.model('User');

router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  User.find(function(err, users){
    if(err){ 
        return next(err); 
    }

    res.json(users);
  });
});
```

And this is the route I made in **index.js**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

The API worked fine using this route but when I changed the above route to a "catch-all" route

```
router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index');
});
```

The API didn't work ( I used Postman for it ) and it returned the `index.ejs` page instead of a json response. Can someone explain why this happened I want to use catch-all route and want the API to work as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What comes first in your code? The route to `/users` or the catch-all route?
You need to define more specific routes first and the catch-all at the end.

```
router.get('/users', function(req, res, next) {
  ...
});

router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Taking the catch-all route at the end worked! Thanks a bunch :)

Comment: I can't even accept the answer as it was answered in less than 5 minutes